# Server API routes returns 404 on Nuxt3 SSG Azure Web App

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to run my Nuxt3 SSG application on an Azure Web App, deployed through a pipeline setup in DevOps. The deployment run fine, though I'm getting 404 errors for all the server API routes when accessing my site. Here are the pertinent files I have setup for the deployment. What I'm trying to figure out is why my server API routes are not being added to my .output folder.

The 404 errors originate from calls to the api routes through $fetch. Since the app redirects to /login, the first error to show is during onMounted of the login layout.

`layouts/login.vue`

```js
onMounted(async () => {
   await $fetch(`/api/startup`, {
       method: 'post'
   });
});
```

`nuxt.config.ts`

```js
import { copy } from '@nuxt/utils';

export default defineNuxtConfig({
    devtools: {
        enabled: (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? false : true),
        timeline: {
            enabled: (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? false : true)
        }
    },
    ssr: false,
    modules: [
        [
            '@pinia/nuxt',
            {
                autoImports: ['defineStore', 'acceptHMRUpdate', 'storeToRefs']
            }
        ],
        '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
        '@nuxtjs/color-mode'
    ],
    css: [
        '@/assets/css/main.css'
    ],
    hooks: {
        generate: {
            after: async () => {
                await copy('server', '.output/public/server'); // Copy 'server' folder to '.output'
            }
        },
    },
    app: {
        baseURL: '/',
        buildAssetsDir: '.output'
    },
    runtimeConfig: {
       ...
    }
})
```

`azure-pipelines.yaml`

```
trigger:
- sandbox

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '18.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
  displayName: 'Install Dependencies'

- script: |
    npm run generate
  displayName: 'Generate Static Site'

- task: AzureWebApp@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'secret-string'
    appType: webApp
    appName: 'secret-app-name'
    slotName: 'development'
    package: '.output/public'
    deploymentMethod: 'runFromPackage'
  displayName: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
```

Additionally, I have a `web.config` file in the root of my project

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="public/index.html" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>

    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />

    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Handle History Mode and custom routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <httpErrors>
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" path="/404.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Also, when the pipeline runs, the wwwroot structure looks like this:

```
/.output
/login
200.html
400.html
favicon.ico
index.html
```

Comment: This YAML pipeline is configured to deploy the app service contents under the path `.output/public`. Can you please check if the contents are correct and expected after the `npm install` step? You can publish this path as build artifacts to check the contents. If you deploy the build artfacts locally(like deploy via [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-deploy)), is the issue reproducible and will it deploy the same contents?

Comment: Since you are deploying to the deployment slot, is there any chance you are viewing the production site? By the way, Azure Pipelines is the automated tool for build and deployment. This check will be helpful to isolate the issue.

Comment: Hi @mojojojo8, Have you got a chance to check the above comments and the answer below? May I know if it could resolve your issue? Thx.

Comment: Hi there, May I know the latest status of the issue and if by any chance you can check the answer or the comments? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I created one sample Nuxt.Js API route and deployed it with Azure DevOps pipeline successfully, Refer below:-

***Make sure you add the API route in your server middleware in nuxt.config.js like below:-***

```js
export default {
  serverMiddleware: [
    '~/api/index.js'
  ]
}
```

**My Nuxt.js app:-**

I created one sample API in example.js file inside api directory in the root of my project, If api dir does not exist create it manually like below:-

**nuxt-api-example/api/example.js:-**

```js
export default (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    res.end(JSON.stringify({ message: 'This is an API route' }))
  }
```

Added the api in my nuxt.config.js middleware like below:-

My nuxt.config.js:-

```js
export default {
  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: 'nuxt-api-example',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en'
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
      { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },

  serverMiddleware: [
    { path: '/api', handler: '~/api/example.js' },
  ],
  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
  ],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/typescript
    '@nuxt/typescript-build',
  ],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
  ],

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
  }
}
```

**Local Output:-**

[image]

Now, I sent this code in my Azure Repository and deployed the App via Azure DevOps in Azure Web app like below:-

**My Azure DevOps yaml code:-**

```yaml
trigger:
- main

variables:

  
  azureSubscription: 'xxxxxxx39f'

  
  webAppName: 'nuxtvalleywebapp9'

  
  environmentName: 'nuxtvalleywebapp9'

  
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '10.x'
      displayName: 'Install Node.js'

    - script: |
        npm install
        npm run build --if-present
        npm run test --if-present
      displayName: 'npm install, build and test'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: $(environmentName)
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy: nuxtvalleywebapp9'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
              appType: webAppLinux
              appName: $(webAppName)
              runtimeStack: 'NODE|10.10'
              package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip
              startUpCommand: 'npm run start'
```

**Output:-**

[image]